# Changing default download directory in Chrome Webdriver

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Can anyone let me know how can I change the default download location for Chrome using Selenium-Perl. I am using Chrome Webdriver and the Perl module `Selenium::Remote::Driver`. I got code for Java but not in Perl for this task.

Comment: If you have Java code to do this then please show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have the test setup but passing below as `desired_capabilities` or `extra_capabilities` to the constructor should work fine.

```
'download.default_directory', 'C:\New_Folder'
```

**Snippet** (untested):

```
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(
    'browser_name' =>'chrome',
    'extra_capabilities' => {
        'chromeOptions' => {
            'prefs' => {
                'download.default_directory' => 'C:\New_Folder'
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**Edit:** Difference between `Selenium::Chrome` and `Selenium::Remote::Driver`

[Selenium::Chrome](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Chrome) allows you to use the ChromeDriver without needing the JRE or a selenium server running. If the ChromeDriver binary is not found, it falls back to the default [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver).

Comment: Thanks a lot Chankey. It worked perfectly. Can you tell what is the difference if I use above Selenium::Remote::Driver with browser name chrome to get driver object or directly use Selenium::Chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chankey.

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles understanding the difference mentioned between `Selenium::Chrome` and `Selenium::Remote::Driver`.  Here's what I got to work:

```
my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new(
    extra_capabilities => { 
        'goog:chromeOptions' => {
            prefs => {
                'download.default_directory' => '/tmp'
            },
            args => [ 'window-size=1950,500' ]
        }
    }
);
```